# Minimizing concave function with a linear constraint

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization

The problem can be formulated as:

$\min f(\textbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \prod_{j \in N(i)}(1-F(x_i))$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq B$

$N(i)$ is a set of i. And $F_{x_i}$ can be any function with range between [0,1].

if $F(x_i)$ is a convex function and $\prod_{j \in N(i)}(1-x_i)$ is concave, the objective function is a concave function.

Is this an NP-hard problem? Is there any possible ways so that I can get the approximation?

Comment: You should look at "convex programming".  Optimization over convex (or concave) functions is usually easier because local minima are also global minima.  I don't understand your objective function though.  What is the $j$ indexing the product?

Comment: As "convex optimization" is usually about minimizing a convex function, and might not be applicable here.

Comment: [A concave function is the negative of a convex function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function), so $\max -f(x)$ is a convex optimization problem.

Comment: The standard form of convex optimization is minimizing a convex function, but here it is maximizing a convex funcion

Comment: Note that "can be formulated as" implies that you can only get upper bounds on the complexity of the original problem, not lower bounds. There may be another representation that opens up more efficient approaches. Meaning, you should explain what "the problem" is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, seems it's not staightforward to find a solution for the convex maximization. I'll try some other representations.

Comment: A couple comments, 1) There's not much to know about convex *maximization* on halfspaces because the only functions that have a maxima are constants. 2) The only convex functions $F$ with range between 0 and 1 are constants.